# GeoDjango could not find GDAL library in Windows 10

Tags: django, windows-10, environment-variables, gdal, geodjango

I am using Django 11.4 on Windows 10 and I am having problems when I try and migrate my models. I receive this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19")
```

I followed GeoDjango's installation instructions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/), but I am still having trouble. Everything I have found on this error says to change the system environment variables.

I installed `OSGe4W` and added `GDAL_DATA = C:\OSGeo4W\share\gdal` as well as `PROJ_LIB= C:\OSGeo4W\share\proj`.

I am not sure what else to try and I would appreciate any more insight.

Comment: Did you try setting? `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 7):

I fixed this by editing the libgdal.py file in %PYTHONPATH%\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal and adding str('gdal202') to line 26 so it reads:

```
 lib_names = [str('gdal201'), str('gdal202'), str('gdal111'), str('gdal110'), str('gdal19')]
```

Depending on what version of GDAL you are using, you may need to add a different version number.

Comment: how did you install gdal?

Comment: @ziggy, these instructions are straightforward: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows

Comment: this worked for me! also this one was super helpful https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246556/installing-geodjango-dependencies-on-windows-10-or-windows-server-2012-r2

Comment: This one solves the issue on Windows for 'gdal303' which is missing. Thank you for sharing, too bad it's invasive!

Comment: if PYTHONPATH is not defined, try looking in folder: `C:\Users\John Doe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and for me the issue was I had started my cmd shell before updating the PATH environment variable used to search for the GDAL library. I just had to restart my shell and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works 100%. Try this if you haven't yet.

First, download the GDAL wheel from [Here](https://github.com/cgohlke/geospatial-wheels/releases)
Make sure to check your python version by opening python in terminal.
You will see an output like this :

```
Python 3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:43:08) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

In the above lines the python version is 3.8.5 and its on 32 bit. So the package that I will have to choose from the link will be 'GDAL-3.3.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl'. You should choose yours similarly.

After you do that just run

```
pip install whl/GDAL-3.3.3-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

After installling GDAL. Paste the following code into your settings.py file

```
import os
if os.name == 'nt':
    VENV_BASE = os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']
    os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.join(VENV_BASE, 'Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo') + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = os.path.join(VENV_BASE, 'Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\data\\proj') + ';' + os.environ['PATH']
```

AND you are good to go.

Comment: the link does not exist anymore so this answer is no longer helpful

Answer (score 0):

After trying many solutions, including reinstalling, adding to paths etc, I found this relatively simple solution which worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49159195/3768552