# OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Trying to install GeoDjango on Windows 10

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgis, gdal, geodjango

I am trying to install GeoDjango on my windows10 using Django 1.11.5 and Postgres SQL 10.4-1 I have downloaded the PostGis files. Created the Spatial DataBase. and followed the instructions on the [install document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows). I am trying to follow the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#geodjango-tutorial). I have made the models. When I try to run migrations. I get the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library 
(tried "gdal201", "gdal20", "gdal111", "gdal110", "gdal19"). 
Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

I tried following a similar [StackOverflowQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313119/geodjango-could-not-find-gdal-library-in-windows-10). It did not work
So I did exactly what the error told me to do. In my settings file I added

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\OSGeo4W64\share\gdal'
```

Now I get the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work I have been at this for almost 3 days uninstalling and installing POstgresSQL. Resetting my Laptop nothing seems to be working